# Spring, Tomcat, Java

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, jvm

When I run .war file in tomcat, the logs show

> ERROR [com.configleon.configurer.WebPropertyConfigurer] - The 'configLocation' variable is not specified in the JVM settings!
>
> ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] - Context initialization failed

And this my code :

```
<!-- configlion property configurator -->
<bean class="com.configleon.configurer.WebPropertyConfigurer">
    <property name="propertyResources">
        <bean class="com.configleon.resource.WebPropertyResources"/>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Anyone can help me please ?

Comment: Try this, I believe the jvm property is not set properly - https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for first one    ERROR [com.configleon.configurer.WebPropertyConfigurer]

see the [here](https://code.google.com/archive/p/configleon/wikis/WebPropertyConfigurer.wiki)

and for second one

```
ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] - Context initialization failed
```

in deployment environment, just make sure your server classpath has included the Spring jar library (e.g spring-2.5.6.jar).

For Spring3, ContextLoaderListener is moved to spring-web.jar, you can get the library from Maven central repository.

Markup

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Where can I put the code to define JVM variable ? I have tried add '-DconfigLocation=test' in my config.properties, but still get same error

Comment: you can put jvm variables in CATALINA_OPT or JAVA_OPT of tomcat web container.